# Deploy RStudio web IDE on Kubernetes via Helm

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rstudio-server, okd

I'm trying to deploy RStudio community on Kubernetes.

I'd like to use Helm in order to facilitate the process (I wouldn't really know where to start if I had to specify the different manifests myself).
I've found [the dsri helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/dsri-helm-charts/rstudio/0.1.21), but of course since it is made for [okd](https://www.okd.io) I can't install it on regular k8 using

```
helm install rstudio dsri/rstudio \
  --set serviceAccount.name=anyuid \
  --set service.openshiftRoute.enabled=true \
  --set image.repository=ghcr.io/maastrichtu-ids/rstudio \
  --set image.tag=latest \
  --set storage.mountPath=/home/rstudio \
  --set password=changeme
```

Is there any way to convert this chart to work on regular Kubernetes? I could switch to okd although I don't really see the benefit of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by disabling creation of Openshift-specific resources. In this case its openshiftRoute. In my case the command looks as follows:

```
helm install rstudio dsri/rstudio   
--set serviceAccount.name=anyuid   
--set service.openshiftRoute.enabled=false   
--set image.repository=ghcr.io/maastrichtu-ids/rstudio   
--set image.tag=latest   
--set storage.mountPath=/home/rstudio   
--set password=changeme 
--set service.openshift.tls.enabled=false 
--set serviceAccount.create=true 
--set storage.enabled=false
```

I've also had to set `serviceAccount.create=true` because Pod was stuck on Pending state without it and `storage.enabled=false` as I don't have any PersistentVolumes configured, but change those according to your setup.